# Sending more than 1 message to TCP server in same connection

Tags: java, ruby, sockets, tcp

I've created a TCP Server in Java and a TCP client in Ruby. The problem is I'm not able to send more than 1 message in the same connection, Only the first message is sent while the other one is not sent.

here is the Java code

```
package com.roun512.tcpserver;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Program {


    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String clientSentence;
        String capitalizedSentence;
        ServerSocket Socket = new ServerSocket(6789);

        while(true)
        {
            Socket connection = Socket.accept();
            BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();
            System.out.println(clientSentence);
            capitalizedSentence = clientSentence + '\n';
            outToClient.writeBytes(capitalizedSentence);
            System.out.println("Sent msg");
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the client code

Client.rb

```
require 'socket'
class Client

        def initialize()
                server = TCPSocket.open("127.0.0.1", 6789)
                if server.nil?
                        puts "error"
                else
                        puts "connected"
                end
                server.puts("Hello\r\n")
                sleep 2
                server.puts("There\r\n")
                server.close
        end
end
Client.new()
```

I'm only receiving `Hello`. I have tried many other ways but none worked.

So my question is how to send more than 1 message in a single connection, Any help would be appreciated :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your server code doesn't even attempt to read more than one input line. What do you expect it to do with the second line? Also, TCP streams are not broken up into "messages". It's a stream, which means you put bytes in one end and get the same bytes in the same order out the other end, but there is no concept of message boundaries.

Comment: I've tried the client on Battlefield server that's using rcon and it gave same result... so it's not the server. Oh and the server is only for testing purposes :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Socket.accept()` waits for new connection after reading the first line.
Try the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String clientSentence;
    String capitalizedSentence;
    ServerSocket Socket = new ServerSocket(6789);

    while (true)
    {
        Socket connection = Socket.accept();
        while(true)
        {
            BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();
            System.out.println(clientSentence);
            capitalizedSentence = clientSentence + '\n';
            outToClient.writeBytes(capitalizedSentence);
            System.out.println("Sent msg");
        } 
    }
}
```

If it works, change `while (true)` to some meaningful condition and don`t fotget to close the connection after the work is done.

Comment: Thanks, now i can see that my client is not the problem :)